Convex with Clerk | don't redirect me to the Login page
my ConvexClientProvider file is:
"use client";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { ConvexProviderWithClerk } from "convex/react-clerk";
import { ClerkProvider, useAuth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { ConvexReactClient } from "convex/react";

const convex = new ConvexReactClient(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONVEX_URL!);

export default function ConvexClientProvider({
    children,
}: {
    children: ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <ClerkProvider publishableKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY! as string}>
            <ConvexProviderWithClerk client={convex} useAuth={useAuth}>
                {children}
            </ConvexProviderWithClerk>
        </ClerkProvider>
    )
}

and layout file is
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import ConvexClientProvider from "./ConvexClientProvider";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ConvexClientProvider>
          {children}
        </ConvexClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


middleware file is
import { clerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export default clerkMiddleware();

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};


Its not showing me any error but also not redirecting me to the login section
want to Protect my all routes using Convex and clerk.
I follow the approach given in official doc, but due to latest updates, I also can't find good answer on Internet.

I just found an answer to that.
To protect all routes of your Site Simply Copy & Paste this code into the Middleware.ts file
import {
    clerkMiddleware,
    createRouteMatcher
} from '@clerk/nextjs/server';

const isProtectedRoute = createRouteMatcher([
    '/(.*)',
    '/',
]);

export default clerkMiddleware((auth, req) => {
    if (isProtectedRoute(req)) auth().protect();
});

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};


I don't understand why this is the second place I've found someone suggest
auth().protect()
If you type it like that, it throws an error: Property 'protect' does not exist on type 'Promise'
I've been using auth.protect(), however also still having problems (though I doubt that's the issue).

to use this code in your convex provider file
'use client';

import { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { ClerkProvider, useAuth, SignInButton, UserButton } from '@clerk/clerk-react';
import { ConvexProviderWithClerk } from 'convex/react-clerk';
import {
  Authenticated,
  ConvexReactClient,
  Unauthenticated,
} from 'convex/react';


const CONVEX_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONVEX_URL!;
const CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!;

const convex = new ConvexReactClient(CONVEX_URL);

const ConvexClientProvider: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider publishableKey={CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}>
      <ConvexProviderWithClerk client={convex} useAuth={useAuth}>
        <Authenticated>
        {children}
        </Authenticated>
        <Unauthenticated>
          <SignInButton>
            <UserButton />
          </SignInButton>
        </Unauthenticated>
      </ConvexProviderWithClerk>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
};

export default ConvexClientProvider;

